# Programmatically add tab bar title and icon Swift

Tags: swift

I am having trouble implementing code to change a tabs title and icon programmatically. I would like to set a custom title and use one of the Apple System images for the bar icon however i am not using storyboards. What is the proper way to do so? This is the code from my `TabBarController`

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[0].image = UIImage(named: "map")
        let mapController = MapViewController()

        mapController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .search, tag: 0)

        let accountController = AccountTableViewController()

        accountController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .more, tag: 1)

        let inputController = InputViewController()

        inputController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(tabBarSystemItem: .more, tag: 2)


        let tabBarList = [mapController, accountController, inputController ]

        viewControllers = tabBarList
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }




}
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Can you explain what the issue is?

Comment: @matt I think the issue is that he wants to use a tabBarSystemItem image with a custom title, which is not allowed.

Comment: @valosip Aha, very good, I see. I thought it was about the construction of the tab bar controller and its view controllers and their tab bar items, all of which is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem/systemitem)

> The title and image of system tab bar items cannot be changed.

What you should do is use the [custom inits](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem) that allows you to set title and image:

`init(title: String?, image: UIImage?, tag: Int)`

So replace how you init the `.tabBarItem` and use your own icons, you can find icons that are very similar to apples online.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let mapController = MapViewController()
        mapController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Map", image: UIImage(named: "ImageName"), tag: 0)

        let accountController = AccountTableViewController()
        accountController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Account", image: UIImage(named: "ImageName"), tag: 1)

        let inputController = InputViewController()
        inputController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Input", image: UIImage(named: "ImageName"), tag: 2)

        viewControllers = [mapController, accountController, inputController ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should put `init(title: String?, image: UIImage?, tag: Int)` ? I am fairly new to swift.

Comment: @AmaniH I updated the answer above so you can use it as an example.  Just change the image names with files/icons that you have added to your projects.